# Can you hide existing standard fields from being seen in Setup? Especially Pricebook2.CurrencyIsoCode

Tags: standard-objects, setup, standard-field

I have a Pricebook2 in a multi currency org. However, CurrencyIsoCode is somehow hidden from me. As unrestricted System Administrator, I would expect to see this field in the Object Manager, but it is ... missing?

In Object Manager I can see these 10 fields:
[image]

And these are also the only ones available in the layout editor.
However, according to Workbench, the CurrencyIsoCode exists:

[image]

Additionally I can query and edit the field in the Query Editor:

[image]

So my question is: how does this happen? Can I hide fields from System Administrators? I have not found anything useful so far, any hint is very welcome.

Comment: There are so many fields that UI hides, it kinda Salesforce architecture. No there is NO FLS setup for Object FLS that you can do to hide certain fields from Admin in setup ui

Comment: That's what I assumed as well as I wouldn't know a way to achieve this either. Probably means something is f*ed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer from Salesforce here is that it "works as designed". Pricebook2.CurrencyIsoCode is not supposed to be available in the UI, only for programmatic access.